# How to put a text higher in beamer?

Tags: beamer

I would like to put the text in Beamer higher, as close as possible to the title, but I don't know how to do it, I would appreciate your support.

[image]

Comment: You could try `\begin{frame}[t] ... \end{frame}`.

Comment: Or if you just want to move the contents a bit higher but not the top, add `\vspace{some value}` at the end to push them up a little.